# getFullAction is not working when cache enabled

Tags: event-observer, cache, magento2.4, full-page-cache, magento2.4.2

I'm looking to set different response headers for different pages. I have tried with `controller_front_send_response_before`. The problem is **getFullAction** method returned the value **(cms_index_index)** correctly at the first time of load. For the second time, it returned triple underscore **(___)**. It returns the correct value when FPC in disabled mode.

**Observer instance:**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Frontend\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as HttpRequest;

class FrontSendResponseBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct(
        HttpRequest $request
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {        
        $fullActionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();
        var_dump($fullActionName); 
    }
}
```

The observer itself has request and response params.

**vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php**

```
// This event gives possibility to launch something before sending output (allow cookie setting)
$eventParams = ['request' => $this->_request, 'response' => $this->_response];
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('controller_front_send_response_before', $eventParams);
```

I have tried the below method as well in the above observer instance but no luck.

```
$request = $observer->getData('request');
var_dump($request->getFullActionName());
```

Any idea about how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer to a similar problem (the event observed was different, but the logic should be the same as in your case) - [getFullActionName() returns empty results for product pages inside predispatch observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332436/getfullactionname-returns-empty-results-for-product-pages-inside-predispatch-o/332439#332439), maybe it helps you.